# How to download a file after making a POST request in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to receive data from a website that makes you fill out a form before you are able to receive the data. I wanted to know if this was possible using the requests library for python. Here is what I have so far.

```
import bibtexparser
import requests

payload={
'displayCitedRefs':'true',
'displayTimesCited':'true',
'viewType':'summary',
}

session=requests.session()
files = open("myfile.bib",'wb')
requests.post("www.thewebsite.com", data=payload)
```

The post request is working just fine. What should I do after the post request to receive the file? Is this even possible using the requests library? 
Thanks!